# How to show selected VARIABLE price*quantity on single product page?

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to show the price on the single product add to cart button
At first I used that popular snippet, but changed it for myself, cause I needed it exactly on the single product page, and not in the loop.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_price( $button_text, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        // shop and archives
        if( is_product() ){
            $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_price() ) ) );
            return $button_text . ' за ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
        } 
            else {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text . ' за ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
    }
   } 

        else {
            return $button_text;
        }
}
```

It worked, but it wasn't ajax friendly -after switching between variations the button text didn't change
So I deleted the snippet and used jQuery to change the button text

```
jQuery(document).on('found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {  
         var qty = jQuery('.summary .quantity .qty').val(); 
         jQuery('.summary .single_add_to_cart_button').html(variation.price_html);     
         jQuery('.summary button.single_add_to_cart_button .price').prepend('У кошик за ');         
      });
```

Now it works fine and [shows the correct variation price](https://terramare.com.ua/product/neapolitan-pizza/) on the button

I still need to change it when the quantity is changing
I tried parseInt

```
(parseInt(variation.price_html))
```

or

```
(parseInt('.woocommerce-variation-price bdi'))
```

It shows nothing. I wanted to get it and multiply it to quantity value.
Where I'm wrong and how to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

What I have for a moment
It works but I'm not sure does it cause any bugs or not

```
jQuery(document).on('found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {  
         var qtty = jQuery('.summary .quantity .qty').val(); 
          currency    = currency = ' <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>',
          vprice       = jQuery('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount').text().replace(/ /g,''),
          parsePrice  = parseFloat(vprice)*qtty,
          totalPrice  = 'У кошик за ' + parsePrice.toFixed(2) + currency;
         jQuery('.summary .single_add_to_cart_button').html(totalPrice); 
            jQuery( '[name=quantity]' ).on( 'input change', function() {
                         var qtty = jQuery('.summary .quantity .qty').val(); 
                          currency    = currency = ' <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>',
                          vprice       = jQuery('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount').text().replace(/ /g,''),
                          parsePrice  = parseFloat(vprice)*qtty,
                          totalPrice  = 'У кошик за ' + parsePrice.toFixed(2) + currency;
                         jQuery('.summary .single_add_to_cart_button').html(totalPrice);   
                });
      });   
    
    jQuery( '.product-type-simple [name=quantity]' ).on( 'input change', function() {
                         var qtty = jQuery('.summary .quantity .qty').val(); 
                          currency    = currency = ' <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>',
                          vprice       = jQuery('.summary .woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace(/ /g,''),
                          parsePrice  = parseFloat(vprice)*qtty,
                          totalPrice  = 'У кошик за ' + parsePrice.toFixed(2) + currency;
                         jQuery('.summary .single_add_to_cart_button').html(totalPrice);   
                });
```